# How to make cross-account call for dynamoDB tables from lambda (Typescript)

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I have a DDB table in account A and lambda function in account B. I would want the lambda in account B to access the DDB table in account A and I believe I need to create new IAM role in account A and assume it in account B to do that. Instead of manually creating roles and policies in AWS accounts I would want to create them in my CDK package. Can someone please share any sample/reference for the same as I am not totally aware of how to do this.

NOTE: I don't want to limit the access to session.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately DynamoDB does not have a resource based access control as of today, so you're right that you need to assume a role isn't STS service.

[This document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/prescriptive-guidance/latest/patterns/configure-cross-account-access-to-amazon-dynamodb.html) describes the process of setting up roles and how to assume it using a Lambda function, which is exactly what you need.